# mod_rewrite PHP $_GET empty

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule api/(.*)$ api.php?m=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

The URL rewriting works great.  I can go to http://myserver.com/api/example and it will behave as if I went to http://myserver.com/api.php?m=example.  The problem is that the PHP $_REQUEST and $_GET variables are empty.  Shouldn't I still be able to get the value of $_REQUEST['m']?

After some googling, I found a suggestion to disable MultiViews.  If I add `Options -MultiViews`, I get a 404 error.

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have mod_rewrite enabled. Since it's not enabled, the `IfModule` container is ignored. See: [How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

You **must** turn off `Multiviews` in order for this to work, otherwise mod_negotiation is activated and will automatically map `/api/` to `/api.php` without giving mod_rewrite a chance to do anything. So you need the line:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

If you can't enable mod_rewrite, you could alternatively change your api.php script so that it looks in the PATH_INFO variable:

```
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
```

to get the "example" part.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled.  I checked phpinfo() and used the function in_array('mod_rewrite',apache_get_modules()).  It is a shared server that I do not have administrative access to, if that matters.  Additionally, the rewrite is actually working - it's sending /api/example to /api.php?m=example.

Comment: Actually I take that back, MultiViews is making /api/whatever redirect to api.php...and then I'm losing the $_GET.  I moved the Options -MultiViews outside the IfModule and that worked.  I still do not understand why I got a 404 error when it was inside IfModule.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because MultiViews was a part of the problem.  I also had to provide the full path to api.php.